# Will Scala support detect implicit parameter from caller rather then from definition?

Tags: scala, implicit

Maybe it's a foolish question but I think the usage is reasonable and useful more then current way to detect implicit parameter.
There is a example what's the means of detect implicit parameter from caller, give the code first:

```
package tagedfuture

class Future[+T](f: => T)(implicit tag: String) {

  def map[B](f2: T => B): Future[B] = {
    Future(f2(f))
  }

  def flatMap[B](f2: T => Future[B]): Future[B] = {
    f2(f)
  }

  def getTag = tag
}

object Future {
  def apply[T](f: => T)(implicit tag: String): Future[T] = new Future(f)

}

object Test extends App {
  val fur = Future{
    10
  }("future-chain-1")

  val fur2 = fur.map(x => x * 2)

  val fur3 = fur2.flatMap(x => {
    anotherFuture(x)(fur2.getTag)
    // expect this:
    // anotherFuture(x)
  })

  def anotherFuture(int: Int)(implicit tag: String): Future[String] = {
    Future(int.toString)
  }

  // expect this:
  //def anotherFuture(int: Int): Future[String] = {
  //  Future(int.toString)
  //}

  assert(fur.getTag == fur2.getTag && fur2.getTag == fur3.getTag)
}
```

`tagedfuture.Future.apply` expect a implicit parameter used to tag where the Future instance come from.
In `anotherFuture` method, it can complied, which has a `implicit tag: String` parameter for transfer the tag when generate a new Future.

We must append the implicit parameter for `anotherFuture` because compiler detect the method context which from `import package`, class  definition place. but not verify by it's caller.

how about support detect implicit from caller?
We can use `//expect this:` which remove all implicit boilerplate code. Even through we removed it, we can get implicit instance from caller in which is first `Future` fur1's `"future-chain-1"`.

It seems more difficult then current implement. Will Scala support this way to use implicit?

### UPDATE

#### What's exactly means of detect by caller in terms of compiler workflow?

Currently, when we defined a method which it use a method has a implicit parameter, like `def anotherFuture`, compiler will check the method context which contains `import pacakge`, 
implicit variable in relative class/object definition and report error if not any implicit to match the method need.
detect by caller means compiler not check the place of the method definition place but check the caller place where invoke the method. At this stage, the caller place is `anotherFuture(x)(fur2.getTag)`. The context contains `Test` object, `fur2` instance and `flatmap` method.
I'm expect it will be compiled by detect the `fur2` instance where has a `tag` variable.

It's different then before but at this stage it can find the implicit by the way and give a elegant code to transfer the implicit context.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what your question is, but you might want to take a look at [this blog post](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/12/07/implicit-function-types.html).

Comment: What do you understand by *detect implicit by the caller* and how does it differ from *implicit not found* error when implicit is missing or providing implicit in context as it is supposed to work?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok, I update it! Thanks for give a read.

Comment: hi, @AndreyTyukin, this is a new consider for implicit and different with current implement strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap, you want the compiler to inspect every variable in scope (at the place where a method with an implicit parameter is called) looking for *any* (public) member of its class that is itself marked as implicit and matching the expected type, in order to provide it to the called method as an argument to the implicit parameter.

I think this would be highly ambiguous (which implicit do you choose if you have two instances of `Future[X]` in scope?), slow down the compiler considerably and would simply not be manageable for the human brain.

So, my answer would be no. (if I understood your question correctly)

Comment: thanks, there are many ambigours even through we define a priority and will make it more difficult to read.